# Python - Why doesn't the length function change for my for loop if I'm increasing the size of a list

Tags: python

I was working on a BFS problem and confused about this line of code  for time in `range(len(rotting_oranges)):` mainly when I added the new positions onto my queue
`rotting_oranges.append((next_row, next_col))`
My question is, a list is by reference. If I added to the rotting_oranges with new positions. Wouldn't the new size of the list be bigger? The question I'm asking is how does the length function called work? In the for loop is it just called once (i.e the `len(rotting_oranges)` )
Here is my full code.

```
    def orangesRotting(self, grid: List[List[int]]) -> int:
        #Rotting orange 
        #0 means no orange
        #1 means alive orange
        #2 is rotting orange
        # Every min the orange adj to me are rotting if I am also rotting. 
        #The first step is to find the dead oranges 
        palin = [1,2]

        seen_set = set()
        rotting_oranges = collections.deque()
        #We need to also know when we're done (i.e) could be no more oranges or 
        #No more alive oranges
        alive_oranges = 0
        
        for row in range(len(grid)):
            for col in range(len(grid[0])):
                if grid[row][col] == 2: #This means dying orange grab you 
                    rotting_oranges.append((row, col))
                    seen_set.add((row, col))
                    
                elif grid[row][col] == 1: #Alive orange add to count
                    alive_oranges += 1 
        directions = [(1,0), (-1,0), (0, 1), (0, -1)]
        
        minutes_passed = 0 
        #Now emulate the dying of oranges every minute 
        #There are two cases either there are still rotting oranges left in our (queue)
        #Or that the alive oranges are still left 
        while rotting_oranges and alive_oranges > 0:
            minutes_passed += 1 
            #This "time emulates the leveling of available" oranges to you at this time 
            #Can also do minutes = len(rotting_oranges) 
            #As one you've popped it the len(rotting_oranges doesn't change until we exit the loop )
            for time in range(len(rotting_oranges)):
                #This means that if the next_row, next_col exist an orange (1)
                #Then we can infect you since row, col are infected and you're just moving within the 
                #4 cardinal directions 
                row, col = rotting_oranges.popleft()
                
                for row_offset, col_offset in directions: 
                    next_row, next_col = row + row_offset, col + col_offset
                    #boundary check
                    if next_row < 0 or next_row >= len(grid) or \
                    next_col < 0 or next_col >= len(grid[0]):
                        continue 
                        
                    #if empty cell can't make a rotting orange so ignore
                    if grid[next_row][next_col] == 0: 
                        continue 
                        
                    #If I've seen this rotten orange before or visited this position before ignore 
                    if (next_row,next_col) in seen_set:
                        continue 
                    #Else you're an alive orange 
                    if grid[next_row][next_col] == 1: #I'd make it rotting then
                        grid[next_row][next_col] = 2 
                        alive_oranges -= 1
                        rotting_oranges.append((next_row, next_col))
                        seen_set.add((next_row,next_col))
                        
        return minutes_passed if alive_oranges == 0 else -1
```

Comment: A for loop `for <assingment target> in <expression>` evaluates `expression` once, and the uses the iterator from the resulting iterable. (If `<expression>` doesn't resolve to an iterable, it errors). So `range(len(grid))` creates a `range` object, and that is what is being iterated over

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The list size does indeed change, but as you have already suspected in your comment, the `len()` method gets only called once and thus the **for-loop** gets assigned the return value of the method when it got called. That's the reason, why changing the size of the list/queue, does not influence the for-loop at all.

Comment: So I don't understand is that if other language like Java where if I had a similar loop it would have still gone into the loop since it has a "new" size. Is there a documentation or reasoning as to why it's like the way in Python.

Comment: @DavidZheng no, in Java, a for-each loop would work in exactly the same way. It could not really work in any other way.

Comment: Sorry I mean let's say we do something like where the rotting_oranges.length() is called each time and given that I do add such values then wouldn't the rotting_oranges.length() be different? Not using a for each loop but the traditional

Comment: A Java `for` loop is more like a `while` loop. There's a condition that's evaluated each time through the loop.

Comment: @David Zheng  Well, one has to bear in mind that Java and Python are different in many ways.  When you write a for loop in Java, it will probably look something like for(int i=0; i<list.length; i++){ do something }.  See the issue? it orients itself on the length of the list! Thus when the list's length increases due to to some operations performed on it inside the for loop, the count of loop iterations also increases.

Comment: In Python, `for variable in range(...)` is not a condition that's tested each time. `range()` is a generator of a sequence of values.

Comment: @Bialomazur thank you for that. That makes sense. So I guess the "for" loop in python is not 1:1 to the "for" loop in java

Comment: @DavidZheng you are thinking of a normal java C-style for-loop, Pyhton doesn't have that. Python's for-loop works like the Java "enhanced" for-each loop, e.g `for (Item item: collection) { / do stuff};` not `for (int i = 0; i <= collection.length(); i++) {...}`

Comment: @Barmar nitpick, `range` is not a generator, it isn't even an iterator. It's a sequence type.

Comment: @David Zheng yes, exactly. It's more something comparable to a while loop in Python.

Comment: Right so just to wrap it all up in the 
for (int i = 0; i <= collection.length(); i++) {...} 
If I were to have collections.append(something) the length would increase hence the loop as well. 
However, this is due to the fact that the for each loop it's size is calculated once? As I mentioned earlier.

Comment: Another way to look at it: the Python loop is like doing `int len = collection.length(); for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)` @DavidZheng

Comment: @DavidZheng a for-each loop is controlled by *the iterator*, it is an iterator-based looping construct. In the C-style loop, it is based on the *termination condition*. If you iteraate over a `range(len(something))` object, it's *size* doesn't magically change when you change `something`, because `len(somethign)` passed in an `int` to `range`, and in any case, `range` objects are immutable. If you iterate over, say, a mutable `list` object, and `for x in some_list: some_list.append(None)` you've just created an infinite loop. Again it works *exactly* like a Java enhanced for loop.